# Is Fable (1996) connected in any way to the Fable franchise from Lionhead Studios?

Tags: msdos, fable-series

I'm a big fan of the Fable games, have played them all on Xbox 360, and recently discovered the DOS game by the same name. I just started playing it and am wondering if it's at all connected to the Fable franchise. It was developed by Simbiosis Interactive and was apparently the company's only release. The vibe that the game gives off, the settings and the cheeky dialogue is reminiscent of the Fable games in my opinion, but I couldn't find a 'yes or no' to my question when I googled it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the games are unrelated.

- As you note, Fable was Simbiosis only release and received very middling reviews.
- [Peter Molyneux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Molyneux) still worked for Bullfrog at this time, working on Dungeon Keeper. So he had nothing to do with Simbiosis title.
- Neither the [1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fable_(1996_video_game)) nor the [Lionhead game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fable_(video_game_series)) wikipedia entries list any connection to each other
- [Fable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fable) is a common english word describing a story, where animals act with human characteristics. Funnily enough, both games pretty much ignore this definition and just use Fable as a different word Story.

Comment: The dictionaries on the front page of a Google search for "fable definition" all mention fables "often" or "sometimes" featuring animals in some manner, so that doesn't seem like a requirement of a fable.

Comment: The linked Wikipedia article itself contradicts the sentence it's quoted in: *"a succinct fictional story, in prose or verse, that features animals, legendary creatures, plants, inanimate objects, **or** forces of nature that are anthropomorphized"*. Speaking animals may be common, it is not more a requirement for a fable than any other anthropomorphized object or creature.

Comment: @zakinster: I don't know about the DOS game, but the Xbox game *definitely* wasn't anthropomorphizing much of anything.